# What API to use to get metadata of asset issuers?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, java-sdk

I am trying to get the metadata (such as organization name, logo) of asset issuers in the Stellar network.

What API should I use that could possibly contain this information when I pass the Public Key, I can't find such API in stellar labaratory?

Answer (score 0):

from [stellar docs](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/ledger/#data-entry) metadata is attached to the issuer account. To retrieve this info you can use the following [api request](https://developers.stellar.org/api/resources/accounts/single/)

`https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/:issuer`

where issuer is the issuer's public key and metadata are the `data` entry in the ouput.

Or with stellar-sdk in javascript

```javascript
const server = new StellarSdk.Server("https://horizon.stellar.org/");
const account = await server.loadAccount(issuerPublicKey);
console.log(JSON.stringify(account.data_attr));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What could be the curl request alternative for the above code? In the metadata above does it include the image of the asset issued?

Comment: @Benji all metadata are stored as a (key, value) pair. With the code above you get a JSON of type {key1: value1, key2: value2, .... keyN: valueN} where value are base64 encoded (you need to decode to binary format before using that values). Anyway I suppose you are trying to get an NFT image. In this case usally the image is stored as an ipfs link or ipfs CID. So once you have the ipfs link you can download the image. For a curl example see my edit.